# How to load different pages in iframe upon request (HTML, JS, Flask)

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I am building an HTML-based page ran with Flask, one of the tasks I am trying to perform is to get different pages to load in my iframe component. Exactly I am trying to display different Wikipedia pages according to a variable from the python program. This is what I have so far:

```
@app.route("/practice", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def practice():
    #Reached via POST
    if request.method == "POST":
        return redirect("/") 
    #Reached via GET
    else:
        return render_template("practice.html", n=random.choice(ls))
```

As you can see, I am rendering the template and passing it the n variable, which just happens to be a random element of a list previously defined. Here is the HTML page, I am just trying to concatenate the variable passed to the Wikipedia URL in order to display that certain page on the iframe, and each time the user reloads the page gets a new aleatory one.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Practice
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var n = {{n}};
        let frame = document.querySelector("frame");
        frame.src = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+n;
      };
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <iframe style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px; object-fit: cover; border: 10px solid black;" src="" id="frame"></iframe>
{% endblock %}
```

However, I'm not getting it to work and instead showing just the blank page.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I feel like your block script runs before your block main which means that the src is overridden to be blank. But I'm not sure if that is the case

Comment: Shouldn't `document.querySelector("frame")` be `document.querySelector("iframe")`?

Comment: @TheGrandJ and @ keanu I recently tried to implement those changes into my code but is still not working, thanks for your input though. Do you have any other ideas?